# Javascript cookie delete

Tags: javascript, cookies

If I create a cookie in Javascript `document.cookie = 'unseen'` how do I delete it when I navigate away from this page? This is the only cookie I am creating on the page.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Run this:

```
document.cookie = 'unseen=; expires=Thu, 01-Jan-70 00:00:01 GMT;';
```

You're not deleting it, but telling the browser it's expired so it'll delete it.

Comment: Thanks. Should do it on page unload event?

Comment: @VictorS - Yep, whenever you want to get rid of it.

Comment: Yeah, I want to get rid of it when navigating away from this page

Comment: By the way this is a content page but it shouldn't matter

Comment: @VictorS - Correct, to the user it's just a html page...just rig up to onunload in your case.  But since this will happen only inside the page...do you really need a cookie?  Seems like it's just a variable unless I'm missing something.

Comment: I need to supress alert message that I pop-up when this page is saved

Answer (score 2):

Set it it to expire to a time in the past. Function from http://techpatterns.com/downloads/javascript_cookies.php

```
function Delete_Cookie( name, path, domain ) {
    if ( Get_Cookie( name ) ) document.cookie = name + "=" +
      ( ( path ) ? ";path=" + path : "") +
      ( ( domain ) ? ";domain=" + domain : "" ) +
      ";expires=Thu, 01-Jan-1970 00:00:01 GMT";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes

```
document.cookie = 'unseen=; expires=Thu, 01-Jan-70 00:00:01 GMT;';
```

but sometimes need to specify path, if the first one failed (not the case of your exact code)

```
document.cookie = 'unseen=; expires=Thu, 01-Jan-70 00:00:01 GMT; path=/';
```

(or use the same library function for creating cookie, but set negative number instead of positive expiry time)

Answer (score -1):

> delete document.cookie

anyways i'm not sure if this is the right way to deal with cookies.