# Delete cookies via JavaScript

Tags: javascript, cookies

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Javascript cookie delete](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2471347/javascript-cookie-delete)

Please let me know how to delete specific cookie (I have the name of the cookie its enough..).

I really dont have an idea (I dont know JS well...) and when I searched in Google I didn't find a good solution.

Thank you.

**EDIT:**
If I can't delete the cookie - let me know how to change the value to "" (empty..), its ok too.

Comment: Are you truly telling us that a search for "javascript cookie delete" did not provide useful results?

Comment: Yes.. I have already tried it, this is why I ask here.

Comment: Tim S. Van Haren's answer is the very first thing that comes up when I google for "javascript cookie delete" as Oded suggested.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Stolen from [here](http://javascript.about.com/library/bldelck.htm):

```
function del_cookie(name) {
   document.cookie = name + '=; expires=Thu, 01-Jan-70 00:00:01 GMT;';
}
```

This sets the cookie value to nothing (`name + '=;`) and sets the expiration time to the past (expiring it immediately).

Answer (score 5):

Try this (adapted from [here](http://techpatterns.com/downloads/javascript_cookies.php)):

```
function DeleteCookie(name, path, domain) 
{
    path = (path ? ";path=" + path : "");
    domain = (domain ? ";domain=" + domain : "");
    var expiration = "Thu, 01-Jan-1970 00:00:01 GMT";

    document.cookie = name + "=" + path + domain + ";expires=" + expiration;
}
```

Essentially, you delete cookies by setting their expiration date to a date guaranteed to be in the past.