# delete cookie with specific name

Tags: javascript

I wold like to use javascript to delete a cookie , the cookie name is "orinet" , I find the link
[Delete cookie by name?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10593013/delete-cookie-by-name) and change it to as below , but do not work , after run it , the cookie is still exist .
What I would like to do is just remove the specific cookie ( or rename it , something like that ) , could advise what is wrong ? or could advise work around method to do it ? thanks

```
<script>
function del_cookie(name) {
    document.cookie = 'roundcube_sessauth' + 
     '=; expires=Thu, 01-Jan-70 00:00:01 GMT;';
     } 
     </script>

   <a href="javascript:del_cookie(orinet);">KILL</a>
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Delete cookies via JavaScript](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3918070/delete-cookies-via-javascript)

Answer (score 0):

You have syntax error in your call, `orinet` should be in quotes:

```
<a href="javascript:del_cookie('orinet');">KILL</a>
```

And also expires is not in proper format. Should be:

```
function del_cookie(name) {
    document.cookie = name + '=; expires=Thu, 01 Jan 1970 00:00:01 GMT;';
}
```

Comment: thanks replies , I am really can't use the above method to remove cookies , could advise if there is other method can do that ? thanks

Answer (score 0):

your expires value is not proper format, change to:

```
function del_cookie(name) {
    document.cookie = 'roundcube_sessauth' + 
     '=; expires=Thu, 01 Jan 1970 00:00:01 GMT;';
}
```

and

```
<a href="javascript:del_cookie('orinet');">KILL</a>
```